# How can I send mails from difrent emails to our users using nodemailer in node.js?

Tags: node.js, email, smtp, backend, nodemailer

we have a number of emails id's

for ex:
**welcome@jhonexample.com** , **reminder@jhonexample.com**, **invoice@jhonexample.com**
etc...

and I want to send emails from each of them, and emails could go at any time and even **simultaneously from two different emails id's** to some number of users (in Bulk)

and here i create difrent transporter for difrent emails

**and some of the emails are automated with cron-job at a particular time every day (where we don't  need to do anything to send the emails) but some emails will be sent via endpoints when they called from the front-end**

```
let welcometransporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "mail.jhonexample.com",
  port: 587,
  secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
  auth: {
    user: "welcome@jhonexample.com", // generated ethereal user
    pass: "********", // generated ethereal password
  },
  logger: true,
  tls: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  },
  pool: true,
  maxConnections: 2,
  maxMessages: 8,
});
```

```
let remindertransporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "mail.jhonexample.com",
  port: 587,
  secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
  auth: {
    user: "reminder@jhonexample.com", // generated ethereal user
    pass: "********", // generated ethereal password
  },
  logger: true,
  tls: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  },
  pool: true,
  maxConnections: 2,
  maxMessages: 8,
});
```

but it showing me error what i could do differently?

```
Error: Invalid greeting. response=421 Too many concurrent SMTP connections from this IP address; please try again later.:
```

Comment: Tell your SMTP Server to whitelist/dont block to many connections attempts from your node app. There is nothing you can do in your app to prevent this. This is a settings that must be changed on the SMTP Server.

Comment: @Marc  let me do that and try. lets see

Comment: @Marc we are using the GoDaddy email server but I do not see any settings there to allow too many connections attempts from same IP address

Comment: Set pool to false, and maxConnections&maxMessages=1. If that does not work, then i see no way to use your application with the godaddy server